# How to solve an audio stream encoding workflow thru pipes only

Tags: bash, audio, ffmpeg, pipe, sox

I have the following workflow which is typically executed on a set of provided audio files (can be MP3 files, as assumed in this example, but also different formats):

```
file000.mp3
file001.mp3
...
```

What I want to achieve is to decode those MP3 files to WAV, concatenate them, run some SoX audio filters on the big file and encode this again, say, with opusenc.

This results in the following separate steps:

```
for i in *.mp3 ; do lame --decode "$i" ; done
sox *.wav output.wav
opusenc --bitrate 64 output.wav output.opus
```

Now I have huge chunks of input files with limited storage available. What I would like to do is to run the whole chain of commands by piping them to each other. I've been trying to work this out with lame decoding to stdin, same with ffmpeg, but to no avail. Although setting the output stream format (which is piped to sox) manually to s16le, ffmpeg complained about invalid format settings and would not successfully decode.

Does anybody have an idea how to create this pipe chain with the commands provided (or equivalent ones)? Would be great to manage this without using mkfifo command.

Comment: You should really add the full command you tried and the full error you saw to you question.

Comment: Also, note that if you do it with pipe (so that the decoded streams will be concatenated), you'll need to make sure no wav header is involved in the process (e.g. `-t` is needed for `lame`). The streams will need to have the same spec as well since you can only indicate one input spec and one output spec for the concatenated stream to be muxed with. No wav header will be there to signifify different different conversions that are necessary. You may want to consider the input file list approach in ffmpeg.

Comment: see also [Piping Sox and FFMPEG together](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98876/piping-sox-and-ffmpeg-together)